# Trying to count the number of rows in excel having a specific text in two different column using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I just started learning powershell and I'm trying to automate an excel report to extract some important info. to make my life easier.

There are 3 possible states (n,l,m) and 3 possible desc (i,j,k) in this report

I have a table like this:

```
|name  | number | state | desc|
| ---- | ------ |-------|-----|
|a     |  1     |  n    |   i |
|b     |  2     |  n    |   j |
|c     |  3     |  l    |   j |
|d     |  4     |  m    |   k |
```

I want to be able to count the number of rows having these combinations in the column 3 and 4: (n,i), (l,i), (n.j), (l,j)

This is what I have done so far but I have tried to many things that didn't work.

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excel.visible = $false
$filepath = "C:\file path"
$WB = $excel.workbooks.open($filepath)
$MN = $WB.worksheets.item("sheet3")
$MN.activate()
$x= @("n","l","m")
$y=@("i","j")
$z=$MN.UsedRange
$count=0
foreach ($z in ($x -and $y)) { ++$count
$rowcount=$count}
write-host "Row count:" $rowcount
```

It is giving an output of 1 and Its more than 1 in the sheet. Please help

=================================================
Going from Owlsleeping solution, I'm trying to filter on dates as well like this:

```
$Content = Import-Csv -Path "C:\file.csv"

$StateFilter = @("n", "l")
$DescFilter = @("i", "j")
$startdate = Get-date -Year 2020 -Month 10 -Day 1 -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$enddate = Get-date -Year 2020 -Month 10 -Day 31 -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59

($Content | Where-Object {$_.State -in $StateFilter -and $_.Desc -in $DescFilter -and $_.Created -le $enddate -and $_.Created -ge $startdate }).Count
```

This is not giving back the accurate count of records created between Oct 1 and 31. Please help

Comment: This becomes much easier if you use one of the existing excel extensions or save file as csv.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping the file is in .xls.

Comment: Then use one of the existing extensions

Comment: @OwlsSleeping the file is now in csv, no difference.

Comment: @OwlsSleeping Now I'm trying to add date to the filter and not getting accurate result. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution for csv input.

```
$Content = Import-Csv -Path "C:\file.csv"

$StateFilter = @("n", "l")
$DescFilter = @("i", "j")

($Content | Where-Object {$_.State -in $StateFilter -and $_.Desc -in $DescFilter}).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the second part of my question:

```
$Content = Import-Csv -Path "C:\file.csv"

$StateFilter = @("n", "l")
$DescFilter = @("i", "j")
$startdate = Get-date -Year 2020 -Month 10 -Day 1 -Hour 00 -Minute 00 -Second 00
$enddate = Get-date -Year 2020 -Month 10 -Day 31 -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59

($Content | Where-Object {$_.State -in $StateFilter -and $_.Desc -in $DescFilter -and $_.Created -as [datetime] -le $enddate -and $_.Created -as [datetime] -ge $startdate }).Count
```